# justify text with setw

Tags: c++, setw

I want to justify the output text like this

```
 0x29823d80    0x10019b8         /    0 00000000000000000000000000000001
 0x37449e60    0x10dfc           /   12 00000000000000000001000000000000
```

However with this statement

```
  fout << std::setw(5) << std::hex << "0x" << (*it).addr << " " 
       << std::setw(5) << std::hex << "0x" << (*it).pc << std::setw(10) << "/" << std::setw(5) << std::dec << (*it).off << "\t" 
       << std::setw(5) << (*it).layout << "\n";
```

I get this:

```
0x29823d80    0x10019b8         /    0  00000000000000000000000000000001
0x37449e60    0x10dfc         /   12    00000000000000000001000000000000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw):

> This value is not "sticky": the next input or output operation that is affected by the value of the stream's width field, resets it to zero (meaning "unspecified").

This means that the `setw` you do is for the string `"0x"` and not the actual hex number. You have to use `setw` *right before* the output you want to justify.

**Edit:** One solution to your problem is to use temporary string containing the leading `"0x"`, and the format with those string instead:

```
std::ostringstream val1, val2;

val1 << "0x" << std::hex << (*it).addr;
val2 << "0x" << std::hex << (*it).pc;

fout << val1.str() << " " << val2.str()
     << std::setw(10 + 10 - val2.str().length())
     << '/' ...
```

The expression `10 + 10 - val2.str().length()` above I get from this:

- The first `10` because you seem to want 10 spaces between the number and the slash
- The second `10` because that allows for 8 hex digits (32 bits) plus the leading `"0x"`
- Adjust for the actual length of the number string

You can see an example using this method [here](http://ideone.com/RdbLWi).

Comment: But that may cause `0x` to be separated from the number. I mean with `setw(5)` we have `0x12345` and `0x  345`

Comment: @mahmood Then you also need to adjust the padding depending on the number of digits for the hex number. Please see my modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may not be what you are after, but remember that `C` is mostly a subset of `C++`, and that you in particular have the function fprintf available, which is much more suited for formatting simple strings and numbers than the `C++` I/O facilities. With this, you would simply write:

```
fprintf(file, "%10p %10p / %5d %d\n", it->addr, it->pc, it->off, it->layout);
```

Comment: But I am looking for solution with `<<`

Comment: Very well. But in general it is good to remember that you have the whole `C` toolbox available, and be pragmatic in using the one best suited for the task, and not being fundamentalist in sticking with the `C++`-only subset.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, use more `setw`! Also, you can use `setfill` to make the numbers look prettier:

```
std::cout << "0x"
          << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(10) << (*it).addr
          << std::setw(5) << std::setfill(' ') << "0x"
          << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(10) << (*it).pc
          << std::setw(10) << std::setfill(' ') << "/"
          << std::dec << std::setw(5) << (*it).off
          << std::setw(33) << (*it).layout
          << std::endl;
```

Produces:

```
0x0029823d80   0x00010019b8         /    0 00000000000000000000000000000001
0x0037449e60   0x0000010dfc         /   12 00000000000000000001000000000000
```